# JaxB takes into account maxOccurs="unbounded" and it it is set, creates the inner element as list for sequence, otherwise just single field

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl

I have such types in WSDL, the only difference is `maxOccurs="unbounded"`, however, the Java classes generated are different:

```
        <xs:complexType name="TypeGetPaymentDetailsAdditionRequest">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PaymentDetails"
                            type="tns:TypeGetPaymentDetailAdditionRequest"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="TypeGetPaymentDetailsRequest">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PaymentDetails"
                            type="tns:TypeGetPaymentDetailRequest"
                            maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
```

The Java classes, the first one have the `List<>` inside, while another doesn't.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "TypeGetPaymentDetailsRequest",
    propOrder = {"paymentDetails"}
)
public class TypeGetPaymentDetailsRequest {
    @XmlElement(
        name = "PaymentDetails",
        required = true
    )
    protected List<TypeGetPaymentDetailRequest> paymentDetails;

    public TypeGetPaymentDetailsRequest() {
    }

    public List<TypeGetPaymentDetailRequest> getPaymentDetails() {
        if (this.paymentDetails == null) {
            this.paymentDetails = new ArrayList();
        }

        return this.paymentDetails;
    }
}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "TypeGetPaymentDetailsAdditionRequest",
    propOrder = {"paymentDetails"}
)
public class TypeGetPaymentDetailsAdditionRequest {
    @XmlElement(
        name = "PaymentDetails",
        required = true
    )
    protected TypeGetPaymentDetailAdditionRequest paymentDetails;

    public TypeGetPaymentDetailsAdditionRequest() {
    }

    public TypeGetPaymentDetailAdditionRequest getPaymentDetails() {
        return this.paymentDetails;
    }

    public void setPaymentDetails(TypeGetPaymentDetailAdditionRequest value) {
        this.paymentDetails = value;
    }
```

}

How one can force to make `paymentDetails` field to be a `List<>` in the second case too?

JAXB version:

```
jaxb "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.7"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `maxOccurs="unbounded"` to the other attribute too:

```
  <xs:complexType name="TypeGetPaymentDetailsAdditionRequest">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PaymentDetails"
                      type="tns:TypeGetPaymentDetailAdditionRequest" 
                      maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="TypeGetPaymentDetailsRequest">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PaymentDetails"
                            type="tns:TypeGetPaymentDetailRequest"
                            maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Is it ok to do, it the wsdl issued on some other side? Is there a way to keep the original WSDL, but change it with some code generation hints?

Comment: If the server has only one element in the wsdl, it will be always only one entry in the interface. Why you want to have a list?

Comment: because of sequence, doesn't it stay for collection? also, missing `maxOccurs` doesn't stay for "only one element presents in a collection"